# Is astrobiology on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

A question that occurred to me in regards to the off-topic closure of [this question about Martian tetanus](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35587/24157), are questions about astrobiology on topic here?

The parts of the question about human exploration of Mars are probably off-topic according to my reading of the [Help Center](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (which probably makes the question overall more of a fit for Space Exploration*). Nevertheless there's still an astrobiology side to the question and I'm not sure where astrobiology questions would fit between here, Space Exploration and Biology (maybe).

Any thoughts? And if we do decide that astrobiology belongs here, should we update the Help Center?

---

<sup>* yes I know that being a better fit on a different site is not a close reason, you don't need to explain it to me, and no I didn't vote to close the question.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think astrobiology as a component of astronomy--that is astrobiology performed using space or ground-based telescopes, should be on topic. Astrobiology that can only be performed by landers/rovers should be left to Space Exploration. Highly speculative astrobiology should be off topic as it is primarily opinion based.